# Can the XYSeriesRenderer area be filled with gradient colors?

Tags: codenameone

I need XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine to be filled with colors with gradients.
For example,

An XYSeriesRenderer fills with green for BOUNDS_ABOVE and red for the BOUNDS_BELOW area.
[image]

But I need the colors with gradients. Gradient blue for the BOUNDS_ABOVE area and Gradient red for the BOUNDS_BELOW area.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You could potentially try to override `drawSeries` and copy the code that's there then replace the fill logic. Or alternatively do something hacky with `drawPath` but both aren't ideal.

You can also add this feature into the code by editing the files in Codename One itself and submitting a PR.

Notice that in the screenshot we have a translucent gradient which I don't think we support efficiently.